# Why CoreApplicationViewTitleBar.SystemOverlayRightInset is 0 in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Why SystemOverlayRightInset is 0 ? In the right side ,there are captions Buttons(Minimize,Maximize,Close).But it returns 0.

My Code:

```
public MainPage()
 {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    double right = coreTitleBar.SystemOverlayRightInset;
  }
```

I need CustomTitleBar , so i set (coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true) . Based on system reserved SystemOverlyRightInset , I need to Place buttons in my custom Region.But here the SystemOverlayRightInset value was 0 ? Why?

Comment: it's  related with element's [FlowDirection](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/TitleBar/cs/CustomTitleBar.xaml.cs#L126)

Comment: here both SystemOverlayLeftInset and SystemOverlayRightInset are zero . Why?

Comment: I tested with official code sample, the SystemOverlayRightInset  is not zero, Can you share a [mcve] for us?

Comment: my Complete code https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lJGRFC04umKXH4mep-_7EsC47ymmZyPm?usp=sharing   . I did not write too much code. Just I try to set ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true and then try to get RightInset!! But its zero ?

Comment: I checked your code, you just set ExtendViewIntoTitleBar as true, but you have not set titlebar content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register on the titlebar's LayoutMetrics changes, like this -

```
public MainPage()
{
      this.InitializeComponent();
      CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
      coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
      coreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged += CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged;
 }
 
 private void CoreTitleBar_LayoutMetricsChanged(CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar, object args)
 {
      var height = coreTitleBar.Height;
      var right = coreTitleBar.SystemOverlayRightInset;
      var left = coreTitleBar.SystemOverlayLeftInset;
 }
```